# Need to upgrade a simple page post back form to use some row "inpage" postback mechanism?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using MVC3, Razor and C#.

I have implemented a simple and robust inline editing solution for a grid.

Basically I use Razor to build my form which encloses the grid, and then the row that matches the item id gets opened up as the editable row which is coded as a partial View.

The Grid View (part):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "GridTest"))
{
<table>
<tr>
  <th>col1</th>
  <th>Col2</th>
</tr>
@{
foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
@{
 if ((Model.ItemId == item.Id))
 {
    Html.RenderPartial("_EditRow", item);
 }
 else
 {
    Html.RenderPartial("_DisplayRow", item);
 }
 }
</tr>
}
</table
}
```

EditRow.cshtml

@Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.Name) 


    Save
    Cancel
    @Html.HiddenFor(p=>p.Id)

DisplayRow.cshtml

```
<td>
    @Model.Name
</td>
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "GridTest", new {id = Model.Id}, null) 
</td>
```

GridTest/Edit Action

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

        var myRecord = db.Orders.First(p => p.Id == id);

        return View("Index",myRecord);
    }
```

GridTest/Edit Post Action

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Order myRecord, string btn="")
    {
        if (btn == "Save")
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Order myCurrentRecord = db.Order.First(p => p.Id == myRecord.Id);
                myCurrentRecord.Name = myRecord.Name;
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(myRecord);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

The above code shows the design. It works greats and is simple. However it causes a postback of the complete page, and I would like to stop this "flashiness". So I suspect I need to somehow tweak the above code such that the "EditRow" posts inline, without refreshing the entire page. I suspect I am looking at using Ajax?

So how can the above code be simply upgraded to prevent complete page refresh, but rather row refresh?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its simplest, you can probably just capture the submit event of the form and serialize that form to an AJAX POST.  Something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $.post('@Url.Action("Edit", "GridTest")', $('form').serialize())
     .done(function(data) {
         // AJAX call is complete
         // do something on the page?
     });
    return false;
});
```

This will use the same controller action in the same way that the form does, just via AJAX.  The controller action will also respond the same way, which probably isn't what you want with an AJAX request.  You might instead want to return some JSON data to indicate success, error conditions, results of server-side processing, etc.  Something as simple as this can just indicate success from the controller action:

```
return Json(true);
```

You can, of course, return any structured data by passing it to `Json()`, which will serialize it to JSON data as the `data` value in the JavaScript `done` handler.

---

**Edit:** If you want to replace a piece of the client-side content wholesale with a partial view, you can still return that partial view in the AJAX request.  The controller action can do something like this:

```
return PartialView("_DisplayRow", myRecord);
```

(Assuming `myRecord` is the type that is bound to that partial view.)

Then you'd have something for the `done` handler in the client-side code.  Maybe something like this:

```
$('tr.someClass').html(data);
```

The idea here is that the `tr` element which is the "edit row" should be uniquely identified in some way (I'm using a class in my selector at the moment, but you can use whatever works for you), and its contents should be replaced with the contents of the partial view being returned from the server-side code.

Comment: David, Thank you for this. I can understand the JQuery that soes the serialization. However I do not understand how I return from the action. The row has to flip back to being "displayRow" and not "EditRow". At the moment I just rerun index which refreshes the whole page. Thanks

Comment: @SamJolly: Ah, I'd missed that.  You could do all of the manipulation client-side in JavaScript (in the `done` handler).  However, if you already have a partial view with the content you want, then you might try something like `return PartialView("_DisplayRow", myRecord);` and then replace the row with those contents client-side.  I'll update the answer with this.

Comment: Thanks for this. What is the "Data" variable? Is this the returned partialView html, ie output from "Return PartialView...."?

Comment: @SamJolly: Kind of.  Completely separate from the server-side code, when a jQuery AJAX call reaches its callback function, it passes a few arguments to that function.  The first (the only one my code is using) is the contents of whatever came back from the server.  In this case it would be the fully rendered partial view.  If the server, for example, threw an error and displayed a default error page, that page's contents would be in `data`.

Comment: Cheers. Really appreciate the help. I think I need to read up on JQuery/Ajax .... :) Thanks again. Really appreciated.